# How to query a closure table to get descendants

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables category and hierarchy

table schema for category:

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Shoes   |
|  2 | Sandals |
|  3 | floaters|
|  4 | men     |
|  5 | women   |
+----+---------+
```

table schema for hierarchy

```
+----------+------------+
| ancestor | descendant |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          1 |
|        1 |          2 |
|        1 |          3 |
|        2 |          4 |
|        2 |          5 |
+----------+------------+
```

How to query to get the data in below order

```
-Shoes
  - Sandals
     -men
     -women
  - floaters
```

I have tried but am new to such complex queries.

Comment: Why are shoes a descendant of themselves?  How many levels deep can your hierarchy run?

Comment: @Chris the above approach to create a table referencing each other is closure method

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the depth of the level can increase as sub categories increase, but for now we can assume it will have upto 10

Comment: I just threw in the towel.  You should use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont have much knowldege in complex queries